# How to make 2nd drop down list auto select value based on 1st drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have two drop down list, one for Client and Location. I would like the location drop down to auto select a value based on the selected Client option.

This is the script i came up with but the value is not being displayed on the location drop down.

```
function defaultLocation () {
  var client2 = document.getElementById('clientList2');
  if (client2.value == "Arm") {
    document.getElementById('locationList2').value == "Cambridge";
  }
}
```

As of now, I want the value to be auto selected when the Client option is chosen with no need to click a button.

UPDATE:
I would still like the user to be able to choose something else from the location list if the default option is not wanted? How would i do that as of right now, once "Arm" is selected, i can't change the location option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign value, you have to use assignment operator (`=`) not `==`:

```
document.getElementById('locationList2').value = "Cambridge";
```

> once "Arm" is selected, i can't change the location option

But I am unable to raise the issue in the following:

```js
function defaultLocation () {
  var client2 = document.getElementById('clientList2');
  if (client2.value == "Arm") {
    document.getElementById('locationList2').value = "Cambridge";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="clientList2" onchange="defaultLocation()">
  <option value="c1">Client 1</option>
  <option value="Arm">Arm</option>
</select>
<select id="locationList2">
  <option value="l1">Location 1</option>
  <option value="Cambridge">Cambridge</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Btw, i would still like the user to be able to choose something else from the location list if the default option is not wanted? How would i do that as of right now, once "Arm" is selected, i can't change the location option

Comment: @Lloyd, please updated the question with relevant html and the point you have mentioned in the comment....thanks

Comment: I had the same JS in the locationList2, changed it and it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lloyd, you are most welcome...really grate to know that you are able to get going:)